# What is the .ajax() equivalent of .load()?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm using an ajax request to retrieve a text string from the server.  I've tried to use .load() but the problem is that it injects the text into the page before running my callback function (which simply displays the text letter by letter).

So, to alleviate this, I've moved to .ajax() and used my function in the success callback. This works as far as displaying the text letter by letter.

Here's my issue. When there are no more strings from the server, the site is supposed to redirect you to another page. This is exactly what happens when using .load().

However, when using .ajax(), the raw HTML from the server is injected into the current page and isn't properly rendered.

I'm not sure how to fix this and I've searched the web for quite some time now. Here is the code for each method.

.load() method (no letter by letter callback)

```
$('#nextButton').click(function(){
  $('#thonow').load('next.php');  
});
```

.ajax() method (with letter by letter callback)

```
$('#nextButton').click(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: 'next.php',
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function(result) {
        $('#thonow').html("");
        lbyl('#thonow',result,0,50);
      }
   });
});
```

And just in case you need the lbyl function...

```
var lbyl = function (target, message, index, interval) {
  if (index < message.length) {
    $(target).append(message[index++]);
    setTimeout(function () {
        lbyl(target, message, index, interval);
    }, interval);
  }
};
```

Any assistance would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: The `.load()` function is just a convenience front-end to `$.ajax()`.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but what are the underlying settings? In other words, what do I need to do in my .ajax() function so that the last request redirects to a page instead of injecting raw HTML?

Comment: @MikelG: see for yourself :) https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/555a50d340706e3e1e0de09231050493d0ad841e/src/ajax/load.js#L46-76

Comment: @Matt yeah I've been staring at that for the last 30 minutes. Unfortunately, it's a bit over my head. I'm still very new to coding. I'm still working through it though... hopefully I'll see something or have a flash of insight.

Comment: @MikelG: Ah. I guess when you say "*the site is supposed to redirect you to another page* ", you mean the site replaces the current page with the response of the AJAX call, rather than redirecting the user via a HTTP request to a different URL?

Comment: @Matt Precisely. Sorry if I didn't make that clear. I even struggled with the wording myself as I typed it.

Comment: In that case, how can you differentiate that response from the letter-by-letter response? What is the top level element in the "replace the page" response? (`<html>`, `<body>`, some `<div>`?).

Comment: Here you go

    `<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en-US"> <head>`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To directly answer your question, the `ajax()` equivalent of `$('#thonow').load('next.php')` would be;

```
jQuery.ajax('next.php', {
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'html'
}).done(function (response) {
    $('#thonow').html(response);
});
```

Note that `load()` has [more logic in it](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/555a50d340706e3e1e0de09231050493d0ad841e/src/ajax/load.js#L46-76), so not **all** `load()` calls are equivalent to this `ajax()` call, but in *this* circumstance, it is.

---

**However**, this doesn't actually help solve your problem. Because your `lbyl` function `append()`'s the response one-character-at-a-time, jQuery is treating each character as a `Text` node*, rather than the HTML string that `load()` treats it as. This is why you see the HTML string being outputted, rather than the HTML string being parsed.

<sup><sup>* `append()` [calls](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/555a50d340706e3e1e0de09231050493d0ad841e/src/manipulation.js#L327-334) [`domManip()`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/555a50d340706e3e1e0de09231050493d0ad841e/src/manipulation.js#L470-557) internally, which itself [calls](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/555a50d340706e3e1e0de09231050493d0ad841e/src/manipulation.js#L497) [`jQuery.buildFragment()`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/555a50d340706e3e1e0de09231050493d0ad841e/src/manipulation.js#L204-288), which [ends up creating a Text node](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/555a50d340706e3e1e0de09231050493d0ad841e/src/manipulation.js#L223-227) if the passed string doesn't look like a HTML string</sup></sup>

What you really need to do is to detect whether the response is a "full page refresh", or a "letter-by-lettter response". Given your [example response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29200720/what-is-the-ajax-equivalent-of-load#comment46613896_29200720), you could do this via:

```
$('#nextButton').click(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: 'next.php',
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function(result) {
        if (result.slice(0, 15) === '<!DOCTYPE html>') {
            document.write(result);
            document.close();
        } else {
            $('#thonow').html("");
            lbyl('#thonow',result,0,50);
        }
      }
   });
});
```

Note that replacing the entire page via AJAX is a bit of a "code smell". I'd rather redirect the user to the new URL, or only replace the page from `<body>` or a descendant.

Comment: This works! Thank you so much. I'll look into your suggestion at the bottom. Thanks again for taking the time to help!