# .load() jQuery function giving back blank div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Thank you in advance for any assistance!

I'm building a crypto relative strength/weakness indicator tool using the [Crypto Charts](https://icnhodler.github.io/CryptoCharts/#/) library. I've got the chart loaded with a handful of coins on the 90-day timeframe to start. The end-goal is to have two inputs from the user:

1. Add new coins to the relative strength/weakness tool
2. Change timeframe of the relative strength/weakness tool

Right now, I am able to add a new coin to the altcoin array `addedAlt`, as well as change the timeframe for the `timeframe` variable. The problem I am experiencing right now is the [Crypto Charts](https://icnhodler.github.io/CryptoCharts/#/) `<div id="mychart"></div>` is not loading back when using the jQuery `$( "#mychart" ).load(window.location.href + " #mychart" );` function to refresh just the `#mychart` div.

I am able to alter the data successfully (by checking the `console.log()`) but I cannot figure out how to update/refresh just the `#mychart` div so users can see the changes they have made on the timeframe & add their favouraite alt to the chart to see it's relative strength/weakness.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Relative Strength/Weakness Tool</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/cryptocharts"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="btn-div"><button class="back-btn"><a href="https://www.binance.com/">Home</a></button></div>
    <h1>Relative Strength/Weakness Tool</h1>
    
    <div id="mychart"></div>

    <form class="timeframe-form">

        <input type="number" class="timeframe" placeholder="90">
        <br>
        <input type="button", class="timeframe-btn" value="Change Timeframe (# of days)" onclick="changeTimeframe()">

    </form>

    <div class="rswtest">

        <p class="rswtest-title">Add Your Favourite Crypto In The Box Below</p>

        <form class="addAltform">

            <input type="numbers" placeholder="XRP" id="submitbox">

            <input type="button" onclick="newData()" id="submit-btn" value="Add Altcoin">

        </form>

    </div>

    <script src="/chart.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
// This is the list of default alts that we have on the chart
var defaultAlts = ["BTC", "ETH", "ADA", "BNB", "XRP", "UNI", ];


// This is the code to add the defaultAlts and submittedAlts together to form the totalList, which is what is showing on the chart.

var addedAlt = [];

var totalList = addedAlt.concat(defaultAlts);

function newData() {
    var newAlt = document.getElementById("submitbox").value;

    var addedAlt = [newAlt];
    
    var totalList = addedAlt.concat(defaultAlts);

    console.log(totalList);

    $( "#mychart" ).load(window.location.href + " #mychart" );

};


// This is where I am creating the timeframe button so the user can change the timeframe of the tool

var timeframe = [90];

function changeTimeframe() 
{
    var newTimeframe = document.getElementsByClassName("timeframe")[0].value;
    var timeframeInteger = parseInt(newTimeframe);
    timeframe.splice(0, 1, timeframeInteger);

    console.log(timeframe);


    // I am currently struggling to find a way to reload the page in order to update the div #mychart. The function below is using jQuery & AJAX to be able to use the $ feature which allowes me to select a particular object/ID/class. I almost have it, I can reload the mychart ID, I just can't get it to pop up again. It just shows a blank screen

    // $( "#mychart" ).load(window.location.href + " #mychart" );

};

// This is the code to retreive the data, as well as the charting library for the relative strnegth/weakness chart. You can find more detail here: icnhodler.github.io/CryptoCharts/#/roi-charts/demos
//person.firstName

CryptoCharts.roiComparison({
    chart_id: "mychart",
    cryptocompare_tickers: totalList,
    last_days: timeframe,
    options: {
      colors: ["#88AA24","#EF1273","#122673","#000000"],
      title: true,
      chart: {
        type: 'line'
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: also of interest is the long version of `load()` https://stackoverflow.com/q/29200720/125981

Comment: Note this code does not look correct with that space in there, `$( "#mychart" ).load(window.location.href + " #mychart" );
` please review the documentation https://api.jquery.com/load/ , this feels more "right" `let urlLoad = "someurl";  $("#mychart").empty().load(urlLoad);`

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss the space syntax is correct (though it won't work as the OP expects). The jQuery `.load()` API has had that feature for a long time. A selector string following the URL (separated by a space) means that when the HTTP response is received, jQuery will construct a document fragment and extract whatever is matched by that selector, and that will be what's added to the target.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to recreate the chart when you change the data. `#mychart` is an empty div, so reloading it does nothing.

```
function newData() {
    var newAlt = document.getElementById("submitbox").value;

    var addedAlt = [newAlt];
    
    var totalList = addedAlt.concat(defaultAlts);

    console.log(totalList);
    $( "#mychart" ).empty();// empty div to be safe
    CryptoCharts.roiComparison({
        chart_id: "mychart",
        cryptocompare_tickers: totalList,
        last_days: timeframe,
        options: {
            colors: ["#88AA24","#EF1273","#122673","#000000"],
            title: true,
            chart: {
                type: 'line'
            }
        }
    });

}
```